# jQuery SimpleModal view once using a cookie

Tags: cookies, simplemodal

I am new to javascript and jQuery. I am using [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) basic to display a message onload when a user visits my site. It's working great, but it repeats each time I visit the page I installed the script. I need this message to be viewed once for the session.

I have searched all over the internet, and have seen that this can be taken care of using a cookie, but I'm not sure of how to tie the cookie function into the function of the modal script.

How can I implement a cookie to track the modal function, and display it only once when the page loads?

Here is the script that loads the modal content:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Load dialog on page load
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal();

});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use cookie , JQuery, Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625395/how-to-use-cookie-jquery-javascript)